# Ant file not able to run Java application via class files

Tags: java, ant, mqtt

I am using Ant to run my Java application. I have my `main` in `Subscriber` class which uses other libraries. So I wanted to run the `Controller.Subscriber`. But I get the following bug:

```
[java] Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback
[java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
[java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
[java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
[java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
[java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
[java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
[java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback
[java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
[java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[java]     ... 7 more
[java] Java Result: 1
```

My Ant file is the following:

```
<project default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <java classname="Controller.Subscriber" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="target/classes"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

The path to the Subscriber class: target/classes/Controller/Subscriber.class

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to first to create jar file from my class files to can run the java program or can I execute the class files? Or do I miss a parameter in my `java` command?

I also tried the following Ant file by giving explicit classpath:

```
 <project default="run">
        <target name="run">
            <java classname="Controller.Subscriber" fork="true" classpath="classpath">
                <classpath>
                    <pathelement path="target/classes"/>
                </classpath>
            </java>
        </target>
        <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="target">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </target>
    </project>
```

But I am getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem: I have to use `classpathref` instead of `classpath`. For some reason `classpath="classpath"` does not read the id `"classpath"`. But `classpathref` solved the problem.